# How do I keep a database physically secure?

Tags: postgresql, security

This is more of a conceptual question. I am learning how to integrate Java and databases (using PostgreSQL at the moment) and my initial questions is:

> What are the guarantees that the data I create will remain safe?

For example, if I have a simple website hosted on my computer, what is the guarantee that data will remain safe from physical elements (HD failure or any kind of hardware deficiency)?

> What are the procedures used in small and big databases to prevent this kind of problem? Should the databases be stored in a separated locked up machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite broad and the answer largely depends on how much your data is worth to you?

If you are from Amazon and you are storing millions of credit card numbers, then loss and/or revealing that data to third parties could be potentially costly in terms of fines from regulatory bodies and loss of consumer trust and future customers.

If they are the scores from your daughter's little league soccer, then the consequences mightn't be as severe financially (although annoyed little girls have ways of making that feeling very clear :-) ).

Maybe you could explain your potential exposure in more detail and ask more specific questions and you might get better advice tailored to your precise needs?

Take a look [here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) (and links within) on how to ask good questions. This site is a great resource and it's worthwhile making the effort to follow the guidelines. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a broad question (and is likely to be closed as such so you might want to describe you situation in more detail), so I'll go for a broad answer in the hope it'll give you some keywords to help research further.

You seem to be more concerned about data *safety* than *security*, but I'll touch on the latter anyway: basically make sure access to the DB is as limited as possible, firewall to prevent outside access, VPN of you need external access yourself, for multiple applications give each is own login and manage read and write access as granularly as you can cope with, and so forth.

Dealing with data safety depends greatly on the importence of the data, it's sensitivity, and the expense of any loss or downtime. Sometimes your clients will express this directly, otherwise you need to define the needs yourself. For instance one of our services carries a guarantee in a disaster situation of no more than three hours downtime and 24 hours data loss, while another more interactive service has similar guarantees set at 15 minutes and 30 minutes - serving that latter guarantee is obviously much more involved (and some are even more fine, some banking services have huge fines for even minutes of downtime or loss).

For some protection against drive failure look into RAID, but never consider that a backup or DR solution. For that you need a proper backup regime. Local onsite (but off-machine) backups for immediate restore, offsite backups for worse situations, and offline for security too. How often you take backups to where and how (full, diff, log...) depends a lot on data size, change rate, and the site mentioned recovery windows. Also replication can provide similar protection to RAID, sometimes better as you can potentially survive machine failure with little or no downtime but remember there are a *huge* family of issues that neither RAID nor replication can protect you from.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if I have a simple website hosted on my computer, what is the guarantee that data will remain safe from physical elements (HD failure or any kind of hardware deficiency)?

You can have a postgres [high availability setup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/high-availability.html).

You also need to avoid these things in order to be safe from database corruption:

- RAID controllers with faulty / worn out battery backup, and an unexpected power loss
- Hard disk drives with write-back cache enabled, and an unexpected power loss
- Cheap SSDs with insufficient power-loss protection, and an unexpected power-loss
- Defective RAM
- Defective or overheating CPU(s)

More details [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).